# Stripe API PHP. Get all payments of subscription by subscription_id

Tags: php, stripe-payments, recurring-billing, stripe-connect

I receive a hook from Clickfunnels that contains a "subscription_id": "sub_AnDOcr3inf0Qfx". How can I get all payments of this subscription using this data? Will be very appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [list all Invoices for the given Customer and Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_invoices) and each of those will have a [`charge` property](https://stripe.com/docs/api#invoice_object-charge) that you can then retrieve (or you could just [expand it](https://stripe.com/docs/api#expanding_objects) for your 'list Invoices' API call).